# Unable to access geometry array of points in pointcloud a-frame and threeJS

Tags: aframe

I have an a-frame entity with a component which is generating a pointcloud made of points in the init function but i am unable to access the points geometry

I had a demo working just using ThreeJS :

```
     for ( let i = 0; i < mainContainer.children.length; i ++ ) {

      const object = mainContainer.children[ i ];

      if ( object instanceof THREE.Points ) {
```

I have set the pointCloud on entity

```
el.setObject3D('pointCloud', new THREE.Points( this.geometry, this.pointMaterial ));
```

i cannot access the geometry in the update function of the component, either using el.getObject3D('pointCloud') or using the id of the entity

Answer (score 0):

As you set the object3D with `setObject3D('pointCloud', new THREE.Points( ));`, `getObject3D('pointCloud')` will retrieve the created `THREE.Points` instance.

The geometry [is an attribute of the `THREE.Points` object](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=points#api/en/objects/Points.geometry):

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("cloud", {
    init: function() {
      // create the points
      const vertices = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        const x = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(5);
        const y = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(5);
        const z = THREE.MathUtils.randFloatSpread(5);
        vertices.push(x, y, z);
      }
      // create a geometry from the points
      const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
      geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
      // small grey points material
      const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: 0x888888, size: 0.05 });
      // setObject3D sets the points under the name 'cloud'
      this.el.setObject3D("cloud", new THREE.Points(geometry, material))
    },
    update: function() {
      // retrieve the THREE.Points object
      const points = this.el.getObject3D("cloud");
      // get it's geometry attribute
      const geometry = points.geometry;
      // log it
      console.log(geometry)
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-entity position="0 1 -4" cloud></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```